# How to find the difference between two files using multiple conditions?

Tags: awk

I have two files file1.txt and file2.txt like below -

```
cat file1.txt
2016-07-20-22   4343250019    1003116 001 data45343    25-JUL-16 11-MAR-16 1            N            0          0 N 
2016-06-20-22       654650018    1003116 001 data45343    25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16 1           N            0      0 N 

cat file2.txt
2016-07-20-22|9|1003116|001|data45343|25-JUL-16 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|hello|table|one
2016-06-20-22|8|1003116|001|data45343|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|hi|this|kill
2017-06-22-22|8|1003116|001|data45333|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|kill|boll|one
```

> Requirement is to fetch the records which are not available in
>   file1.txt using below condition.

```
file1.txt                  file2.txt 
col1(date)                 col1(Date)
col2(number: 4343250019 )  col2(last value of number: 9)
col3(number)               col3(number)
col5(alphanumeric)         col5(alphanumeric)
```

Expected Output :

```
2017-06-22-22|8|1003116|001|data45333|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|NULL|0|0|N|kill|boll|one
```

> This output line doesn't available in file1.txt but available in
>   file2.txt after satisfying the matching criteria.

I was trying below steps to achieve this output -

```
###Replacing the space/tab from the file1.txt with pipe
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' OFS="|" file1.txt > file1.txt1

### Looping on a combination of four column of file1.txt1 with combination of modified column of file2.txt and output in output.txt
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {a[$1FS$2FS$3FS$5];next} {(($1 FS substr($2,length($2),1) FS $3 FS $5) in a) print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt1 > output.txt

###And finally, replace the "N" from column 8th and put "NULL" if the value is "N".
awk -F'|' '{ gsub ("N","NULL",$8);print}' OFS="|" output.txt >  output.txt1
```

> What is the issue?

My 2nd operation is not working and I am trying to put all 3 operations in one operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat f1
2016-07-20-22   4343250019    1003116 001 data45343    25-JUL-16 11-MAR-16 1            N            0          0 N 
2016-06-20-22       654650018    1003116 001 data45343    25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16 1           N            0      0 N 

$ cat f2
2016-07-20-22|9|1003116|001|data45343|25-JUL-16 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|hello|table|one
2016-06-20-22|8|1003116|001|data45343|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|hi|this|kill
2017-06-22-22|8|1003116|001|data45333|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|kill|boll|one
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,substr($2,length($2)),$3,$5];next}!(($1,$2,$3,$5) in a)' f1 FS="|" f2
2017-06-22-22|8|1003116|001|data45333|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|kill|boll|one
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '                                          # call awk.
 FNR==NR{                                      # This is true when awk reads first file
           a[$1,substr($2,length($2)),$3,$5]   # array a where index being $1(field1), last char from $2, $3 and $5
           next                                # stop processing go to next line
        }
        !(($1,$2,$3,$5) in a)                  # here we check index $1,$2,$3,$5 exists in array a by reading file f2
       ' f1 FS="|" f2                          # Read f1 then 
                                               # set FS and then read f2
```

- > `FNR==NR`  If the number of records read so far in the current file
  >   is equal to the number of records read so far across all files,
  >   condition which can only be true for the first file read.
- > `a[$1,substr($2,length($2)),$3,$5]` populate array "a" such that the
  >   indexed by the first
  >   field, last char of second field, third field and fifth field from 
  >   current record of file1
- > `next` Move on to the next record so we don't do any processing
  >   intended    for records from the second file.
- > `!(($1,$2,$3,$5) in a)` IF the array `a` index constructed from the
  >   fields (`$1,$2,$3,$5`) of the current record of file2 does not exist
  >   in array `a`, we get boolean true **(`!` Called Logical NOT Operator. It is used to reverse the logical state of its operand. If a condition is true, then Logical NOT operator will make it false and vice versa.)** so awk does default operation `print $0` from file2
- > `f1 FS="|" f2` read file1(`f1`), set field separator "|" after
  >   reading first file, and then read file2(`f2`)

**--edit--**

> When filesize is huge around 60GB(900 millions rows), its not a good
>   idea to process the file two times. 3rd operation - (replace "N" with
>   "NULL" from col - 8 ""awk -F'|' '{ gsub ("N","NULL",$8);print}'
>   OFS="|" output.txt

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{
         a[$1,substr($2,length($2)),$3,$5];
         next
      }
     !(($1,$2,$3,$5) in a){ 
         sub(/N/,"NULL",$8); 
         print
     }' f1 FS="|" OFS="|" f2

2017-06-22-22|8|1003116|001|data45333|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|NULL|0|0|N|kill|boll|one
```

Comment: I appreciate your explanation (+1) but How can we handle 3rd condition too with the above cmd. When filesize is huge around 60GB(900 millions rows), its not a good idea to process the file two times.
3rd operation - (replace "N" with "NULL" from col - 8

""awk -F'|' '{ gsub ("N","NULL",$8);print}' OFS="|" output.txt""

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: Hi vipin see my update, you just have to modify like this `!(($1,$2,$3,$5) in a){ sub(/N/,"NULL",$8); print}' f1 FS="|" OFS="|" f2`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[|]|[[:blank:]]+' 'FNR==NR{E[$1($2%10)$3$5]++;next}!($1$2$3$5 in E)' file1.txt file2.txt
```

and your sample output is *wrong*, it should be (last field if different: data453**3**3)

```
2016-07-20-22|9|1003116|001|data45333|25-JUL-16 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|hello|table|one
2017-06-22-22|8|1003116|001|data45343|25-JUL-17 11-MAR-16|1|N|0|0|N|kill|boll|one
```

Commented code

```
# separator for both file first with blank, second with `|`
awk -F'[|]|[[:blank:]]+' '
   # for first file
   FNR==NR{
      # create en index entry based on the 4 field. The forat of filed allow to use them directly without separator (univoq)
      E[ $1 ( $2 % 10 ) $3 $5 ]++
      # for this line (file) don't go further
      next
      }

   # for next file lines

   # if not in the index list of entry, print the line (default action)
   ! ( ( $1 $2 $3 $5 ) in E ) { print }
   ' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: I have updated sample output and how can we handle 3rd operation within your command(removal of "N" with "NULL". One way is to use sed with pipe within awk but the problem is - we don't know weather it will be first "N" or last "N" of line, the only way to make sure we are removing "N" with "NULL" from 8th column is sub or gsub.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk -F'[ |]*' 'NR==FNR{su=substr($2,length($2),1); a[$1":"su":"$3":"$5]=1;next} !a[$1":"$2":"$3":"$5]{print $0}' f1 f2
```

Here,

- `a[]` - an associative array
- `$1":"su":"$3":"$5` - this forms key for an array index. `su` is last digit of field `$2` (`su=substr($2,length($2),1)`). Then, assigning an `1` as value for this key.
- `NR==FNR{...;next}` - this block works for processing `f1`.

**Update:**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{$2=substr($2,length($2),1); a[$1":"$2":"$3":"$5]=1;next} !a[$1":"$2":"$3":"$5]{gsub(/^N$/,"NULL",$8);print}' f1 FS="|" OFS='|' f2
```

Comment: It is working for first 2 condition, i will try to figure it out for 3rd condition but can you please explain this part - 

a[$1":"su":"$3":"$5]=1;next}